# C++ ODR-rule for default arguments of template functions

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

In the current draft of the C++ standard, there is the following paragraph ([[temp] p.6]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#6)):

> A template name has linkage. Specializations (explicit or implicit) of a template that has internal linkage are distinct from all specializations in other translation units. A template, a template explicit specialization, and a class template partial specialization shall not have C linkage. Use of a linkage specification other than "C" or "C++" with any of these constructs is conditionally-supported, with implementation-defined semantics. Template definitions shall obey the one-definition rule. [ **Note: Default arguments for function templates and for member functions of class templates are considered definitions for the purpose of template instantiation ([temp.decls]) and must also obey the one-definition rule. — end note** ]

I do not understand what the highlighted part means. How could I break the one definition rule using default arguments? Is there a way to "re-define" them?

Comment: Am guessing but `#define`(s) changing between compilation units changing the default arguments.

Comment: But wouldn't that violate http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12.1?

Comment: I guess it would - suggest adding [language-lawyer]  tag.

Comment: Like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yHXzkfTIhpJA98c6)?

Comment: @xskxzr Ok, but this problem is not specific to templates, right? So why would it be mentioned here? And I don't see how "[...] are considered definitions for the **purpose of template instantiation**" and "must also obey the one-definition rule" are linked. Or are those statements not related?

Comment: I think it is referring to the default value of the argument, since the [temp.decls] section mentions that each default argument is a separate definition.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes, I read [temp.decls] p.2 as well. I believe that tries to say that when you instantiate a template, the default arguments do not automatically get instantiated as well, since only declarations "inside" a template are instantiated alongside the instantiation of the template.

Comment: I feel like this note references [temp.inst/2.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.inst-2.2), which has very similar wording

Answer (score 0):

The OP seems to be asking a few different questions:

1. What does the first part ("considered definitions for the purpose of template instantiation") mean?
2. What does the second part ("must also obey the one-definition rule") mean?
3. Isn't the part about the one-definition rule redundant with [basic.def.odr]/14.4 (which, at the time, was known as [basic.def.odr]/12.1)?
4. Assuming that the intent is *e.g.* to prohibit the same function template from having two different default arguments for the same parameter in different translation units such that the two default arguments don't have the same value, is this issue specific to templates? If not, then why does it need to be mentioned here at all?

#### Answer to question 1

That part of the note references [temp.decls], and [temp.decls.general]/3 elaborates:

> For purposes of name lookup and instantiation, default arguments, *type-constraint*s, *requires-clause*s (13.1), and *noexcept-specifier*s of function templates and of member functions of class templates are considered definitions; each default argument, *type-constraint*, *requires-clause*, or *noexcept-specifier* is a separate definition which is unrelated to the templated function definition or to any other default arguments, *type-constraint*s, *requires-clause*s, or *noexcept-specifier*s. For the purpose of instantiation, the substatements of a constexpr if statement (8.5.2) are considered definitions.

Thus, it seems to be simply reminding the reader that default arguments are subject to instantiation separately from the function templates (or member functions of class templates) that they belong to.

#### Answer to question 2

The part about the one-definition rule appears to be reminding the reader that if the same default argument of a function template (or member function of class template) appears in multiple translation units, those multiple definitions must be "the same" in the sense of the one-definition rule ([basic.def.odr]/14). xskxzr already gave an example of how this could potentially be violated:

```
// TU 1
template <typename T> void foo(int = 0);

// TU 2
template <typename T> void foo(int = 1);
```

#### Answer to question 3

In the current standard, default arguments are a kind of "definable item" ([basic.def.odr]/1.6) so the rule that multiple definitions in different translation units must be identical applies to them just as it does to class definitions, inline function definitions, and so on ([basic.def.odr]/14). This does make the note redundant, which is fine. Notes are non-normative, so they ought to be redundant. Notes are often used to clarify normative text or to draw the reader's attention to a possibly surprising consequence of the normative text.

#### Answer to question 4

The first half, about instantiation, is obviously specific to templates. The second half is not now specific to templates, but it used to be. In C++20, it was made illegal for the same function parameter to be given different default arguments by different translation units; prior to C++17, it was legal. (This is [diff.cpp17.dcl.dcl]/2 in the "Compatibility" section of C++20.)

To be specific, from C++98 through C++17, therefore, it was permitted for *non-template* functions to have different default arguments in different translation units, but it was not permitted for function templates; therefore, the rule about default arguments being definitions that are subject to the one-definition rule was specific to function templates (and member functions of class templates). The wording of the note has not changed since C++98.

It might be more clear if the wording of the note were now changed to:

> Default arguments for function templates and for member functions of class templates are considered definitions for the purpose of template instantiation ([temp.decls]) and**, like default arguments of non-templated functions,** must also obey the one-definition rule.

I don't think this change is necessary, though. The standard cannot be expected to be a particularly well-written document, as it is maintained by volunteers who already have their hands full with determining what the normative rules should be. You should expect that there will be times when you will look at something in the standard and wonder "why isn't this written in a different way?" And usually there will be some historical reason, but even if you can't figure out what that reason is, you shouldn't let it detract from your ability to understand what the standard is saying.