# Best way of pulling a default value from preprocessor without causing an ODR violation

Tags: c++, c++23

Given a set of logging functions that takes in a "tag" along with the usual format string arguments:

```
struct Tag { std::string_view value; };

template<class ... Args>
inline void log(Tag tag, std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&& ... args);
```

With usage:

```
log({"subsystemA"}, "Hello World {}", 0);
log({"subsystemB"}, "Informational message");
```

It turns out that the most common value for `tag` is just the name of the current target library/module/executable name.

If I have the build system create a preprocessor definition `CURRENT_TARGET_NAME` for each source file, what would be the best way to construct a logging function that automatically injects this value?

An obvious, but wrong, solution is to use the macro definition in an `inline` function as this is an ODR violation.

```
template<class ... Args>
inline void log(std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&& ... args) { 
    log({CURRENT_TARGET_NAME}, fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Same for trying to inject it as a template argument.

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct StringLiteral { 
    constexpr StringLiteral(const char(&str)[N]) {
        std::copy_n(str, N, value);
    }       

    char value[N]; 
};

template<StringLiteral Tag = CURRENT_TARGET_NAME, class ... Args>
inline void log(std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&& ... args) {
    log({Tag.value}, fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

My understanding is that these violate the `each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens (typically, appears in the same header file)` requirement for inline functions. Although in the case of the template parameter, it appears to work "fine", so I'm not sure.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

A kind of workable solution is to use preprocessor macros instead of inline functions, as this definitely doesn't cause an ODR violation. It does make the logging system a pain to extend in the future though, as true functions are easier to work with.

```
#define log(fmt, ...) log_impl({CURRENT_TARGET_NAME}, fmt __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: The default template argument looks ok to me.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sounds like it's an odr violation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958103/c-odr-rule-for-default-arguments-of-template-functions

Comment: @AlanBirtles I should've clarified. I know it's a violation, but it should work in practice, unlike embedding the value into a function body.

Comment: This is a very similar requirement to `std::source_location::current` which requires compiler support to implement. Think you might have to stick with the macro version

Comment: I didn't even consider this is similar to `source_location`. Annoying macros, annoying macros for all!

Comment: Nothing wrong with using macros, yes there's a lot of things which can now be done without them in c++ but they're sometimes still the best tool for the job